# Unable to acces .json file while in JS script useing Node.js Express

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, d3.js

I'm trying to access data from data.json in my Node.js Express app but am unable to do so.

My project looks as follow:

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var d3 = require("d3");


//set which viewengine is used
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//serving static files in Puclib folder
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//render index.ejs from ./views when visiting localhost:3000
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index');

});
//use port 3000
app.listen(3000);
```

Within index.ejs I am trying to use css and js by linking to them as you normally would.

In my main.js file I am trying to load in data.json I got stored in public/data/

```
window.onload = function () {
console.log('Js is working');
    d3.json("data/data.json", function (error, data){
      console.log(data);
    })
}
```

I am able to see the "js is working" log in the console but I am not able to find data.json

My project folder is structured like this:

```
/public
   /css
      style.css
   /data
      data.json
   /js
      main.js
/views
   index.ejs
app.js
```

Comment: Are you using D3 **v5**?

Comment: Also `data/data.json` is not a valid path. You would want `./data/data.json` the `./` at the beginning are important.

Comment: @pmkro thanks for the correction! However, I changed the path but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: That link assumes your `html/php` file is in the same location as your `app.js`

Comment: @pmkro I'm sorry, could you be more clear about which link you mean? I've been learning Node since 2 days so I am pretty new to everything. Thanks for your responses so far!

Comment: @altocumulus I am currently using d3@4.13.0

Comment: Nope sorry thats my bad, forgot its in node. I'm assuming you are running `app.js`

Comment: Change `data/data.json` to `/data/data.json`

Comment: @pmkro yes app.js is running. I'm also sure the js file is working since the console.log outside of the d3 function is working.

Comment: @FranciscoMateo I've tried that but unfortunately it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(error)` that might give more information. The request is failing in the call so its probably throwing an error

Comment: @pmkro I'm not able to log anything within the d3 function. Also       console.log('test'); is not logging anything.

Comment: To be absolutely sure, can you please replace the first, outer `console.log()` with `console.log(d3.version)`.

Comment: @altocumulus Oh man, you are right. The log showed: 5.1.0  Does this mean I should use different notation?

Comment: @MartijndeWin Yes, this is a duplicate of the question I linked to in the above comment. You either switch over to using Promises in your browser code or you downgrade to v4. I'd go with the former. And, if possible, I'd upgrade the backend version as well.